# How can I make a window unclickable?

Tags: window-manager

I would like to be able to "click through" a certain window as if it was not there. How can I set this up?

Comment: Like the notify-osd notifications?

Comment: @George Edison Yes, like the notify-osd notifications, but without becoming transparent.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin called "ghost" which allows you do to this in compiz (if you are using compiz). I haven't tested it for a while though.

This plugin is supposed to allow you to make a window unclickable (a "ghost" of sorts).

Comment: i've searched and searched for it, and i have been unable to find anyting except references to it.. anyway nothing that will work on 14.04

Comment: i wish there was a "message" we could send to a window that will make it click-through