# Looking for a linux equivalent to Trans Lucy

Tags: software-recommendation, video, mac, transparency, productivity

Trans Lucy for the Mac, allows you to watch video in a semi transparent window, superimposed on top of your other windows.

You can continue to work, as all clicks on the area covered by Trans Lucy pass directly to the window below - as if the window wasn't there.

Does anyone know of an equivalent for Linux?

Comment: Might be useful: [How can I make a window unclickable?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41934/how-can-i-make-a-window-unclickable)

Comment: Pretty sure you can do it with Compiz... Usually I just stick the video to my desktop and make all my other windows transparent so I can see the video through them.

Answer (score 3):

Just realize that this is not enabled by default in Unity. So, install compizconfig-settings-manager:

```
apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Run it by search for program ccsm. Then enable the "Opacity, Brightness, and Saturation" settings. Now you can control the opacity of any windows by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse_Scroll</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Okay since it is hard for me to explain in words you can view a tutorial I made on how to do it

[Give a Video Player Transparencey in Ubuntu 11.04 & 11.10](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slzk9zBCcR4)

You can sort of do this in reverse to what I did where you add transparency to all windows that you will be using, otherwise there is no other way to see a movie through a window because the window will snap to the top.

Answer (score -2):

For Gnome You may also take a look at [Devil's pie](http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie). The possibilities are quite numerous.

Comment: care to elaborate how?

Comment: How do you do the semi-transparent window with devilspie?

Comment: Explain the gist of how to do things here and give a link to the specific tutorial.